# Ignore escape sequences in PHP while fwrite

Tags: php, escaping, fwrite

Is there a way to ignore characters like `'\n'` while using `fwrite` and print them as is in the file?

```
$x = "Some data with \nslash n";
fwrite($fp, $x."\r\n");

Gives me : 
Some data with
slash n
```

I know using a single quote would solve my problem but `$x` is coming from somewhere else so its value is already set.

Answer (score 0):

If you are escaping only new line characters, append the [PHP_EOL](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) constant to the string, right at the position where you want the line break. So for example:

```
$x = "Some data with".PHP_EOL."slash n";
```

Comment: Ahh! Data is 2.5 GB, and might have other escape characters too. All I want is for it to be written "as is" ...am reading from one file and putting to another after some processing.

Answer (score 0):

I have a bad answer, but maybe it would help:

```
fputs($fp, str_replace(["\r","\n"],["\\r","\\n"],$x."\r\n")."\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is in double and single quotes

Use double quotes while searching in str_replace and use single quotes while putting the value back

To just replace and download file to your PC, here is the code:

```
<?php
    $a = "My Name\n is Ashwani";
    $b = str_replace("\n",'\n',$a);
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=output.txt');
    header('Content-type: text/plain');
    echo "This is the original data:\n".$a;
    echo "\n\n\nThis is the replaced data:\n".$b;
?>
```

To write a file on the server with output and extension csv, here is the code:

```
<?php
    $a = "My Name\n is Ashwani";
    $b = str_replace("\n",'\n',$a);
    $h = fopen("output.csv","w");
    fwrite($h,"This is the original data:\n".$a);
    fwrite($h,"\n\n\nThis is the replaced data:\n".$b);
    fclose($h);
?>
```

Hope this helps